# Quicksight calculated filed displayed total wrong

Tags: amazon-redshift, pivot-table, dashboard, business-intelligence, amazon-quicksight

i am using a pivot table in quicksight. I have three value columns - count, col a, [col a/ count]. third column is a calculated field with formula col a / count. The total shown at the bottom of the table is wrong as it shows division of all [col a] column values and sum of all values in [Count] column. I simply want the total of just [col a / count] column which should be 8172.

[image]